# Multiple variables using $watchGroup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

my watchgroup isnt working, it gives me undefined, am i doing anything wrong in my code?

```
 $scope.$watchGroup([vm.footer.nrRows, vm.isSaved], function(current, original) {

            console.log("Nr Rows "+current[0]);
            console.log("is saved? "+current[1]);
        });
```

Comment: You just need to put it the variables as `String`.

Comment: can you take a look at my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187883/multiple-variables-using-watchgroup/38188124#38188124

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(["vm.footer.nrRows", "vm.isSaved"], function() {
   ...
}, true);
```

If your variable is `$scope.something` you should put in $watch like `"something"`

Comment: I just made the change, and it works when is first loaded, but after it just stops watching, i keep changing the value and the watcher isnt working.

Comment: @MarcoPereira Check the updated answer. pass "true" for the second param.

Comment: Yes, i added that parameter also, but sill isnt watching

Comment: @MarcoPereira could you please put your code in plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.footer = {};
  $scope.footer.nrRows = 5;
  $scope.isSaved = true;
  $scope.$watchGroup(['footer.nrRows', 'isSaved'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    console.log(oldValues);
    console.log(newValues);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>      
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="footer.nrRows" />
  <span ng-bind="footer.nrRows"></span>
  <hr />
  <input ng-model="isSaved" />
  <span ng-bind="isSaved"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, but still cant figure out what difference made comparing with other solutions above, only this solution above worked for me. Hope for someone to explain me why.

Solution:

```
 $scope.$watchGroup([
            function(){
                return vm.footer.nrRows;
            }, function(){
                return vm.isSaved;
            }
        ], function(newValues, oldValues){
            var newProp1 = newValues[0];
            var newProp2 = newValues[1];
            console.log("newProp1");
            console.log(newProp1);
            console.log("newProp2");
            console.log(newProp2);
        });
```

Comment: What happens when you try my solution?